# Angular2 application install & run via package.json possible?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

My question is related to this question that was asked 4 days ago: (URL#1) [How to start Angular2 project with minimum of required files using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650317/how-to-start-angular2-project-with-minimum-of-required-files-using-npm)

I use the same package.json that was mentioned in the above URL and I am doing the same project. I get the following errors, for which I think the solution is: (URL#2) https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8048

However, I want confirmation from someone that I have identified correctly what the problem is that is causing these errors. I am in the process of implementing the suggestions in #URL2 to see if my problem vanishes. I am trying this out (i.e "npm start" command) both on Windows 7 & Windows 10 & getting error in both OS.

For your benefit here is the detailed list of errors: 
error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\dev4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
 error npm  v3.5.3
 error code ELIFECYCLE
 error angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrent "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"`
 error Exit status 1
 error Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'concurrent "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
 error not with npm itself.
 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 error     concurrent "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
 error     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 error     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
 error There is likely additional logging output above.
 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Thank you for your time.

-Srikanth

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what solution you're referring to in that second (github) link, unless you mean you're working behind a proxy, and setting `http_proxy` correctly resolves your issue.

Having gone through this recently, here is how I got things working.  My versions for reference...

> @>node -v
>
> v5.4.1
>
> @>npm -v
>
> v3.3.12

I was having issues updating to the latest TypeScript compiler.  No matter what `npm` command I tried it would not install/update from the version I had on my system (v1.0.3.0 - from a Visual Studio install).  Also, `concurrent` (node package `concurrently`) and `lite-server` were apparently not installed via `package.json` when I ran the initial install.  The error I was receiving was:

> npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

(The Angular 2 "Getting Started" guide said to ignore the errors, so I did for a while...)

---

### Addressing the SSL certificate issue

I eventually realized nothing was being installed due to this cert. error.  I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22099098/4342563), and tried several of the answers, but given my work environment I ended up temporarily allowing use of HTTP instead of HTTPS, like so...

**WARNING: do this at your own risk, and consider setting this back to `true` immediately afterwards, if you use this**

`npm set strict-ssl false`

But if it works for you I would recommend using known registrars via...

`npm config set ca=""`

---

### Fix the install (Edited)

Then you should run the `npm install`, or `npm update` if you already have, in the `angular2-quickstart` directory, after resolving the SSL certificate issue.  Doing so, you will notice that much of the initial install would have failed, including the install of the other core dependencies (like `angular2`).  I was focused on the development environment itself (typescript, lite-server, etc.) and had completely overlooked the fact that these libraries for the application itself were never installed.

---

Leaving this for reference...

If you want to explicitly install/update just those packages listed under `devDependency` section of `package.json`, you can run...

```
npm install -g concurrently typescript lite-sever
```

Thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34367208/4342563) for helping me realize the package for the `concurrent` program is called `concurrently`.

---

### Latest TypeScript complier (Edited)

I had originally mentioned the `package.json` referencing TypesSript v1.7.3, but it references `^1.7.3`, or ">= 1.7.3", so it doesn't need to change to handle the latest version (v1.7.5 at the time of writing this).