# Which angular2 script needs to be included in order to run basic Angular 2 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I'm following along in the new Tuts+ course on Angular 2 https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/whats-new-in-angular-2/lessons/angular-2-and-es5

The author mentions including this script:
`<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>`

However with the current latest beta build of [Angular2](https://github.com/angular/angular), this file does not exist.

These are the files I currently see, I've tried including several of the files below, however I'll get different errors like missing Observables or System.

Anyone else running into this problem with Angular2?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might want to check the 5 min quickstart on Angular's main page. Also take a look at this question:

[How to start Angular2 project with minimum of required files using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650317/how-to-start-angular2-project-with-minimum-of-required-files-using-npm/34682938#34682938)

The file you are looking for is `angular2.js` or `angular2.dev.js`

Comment: Thanks! Will accept in 7 minutes, now I have a new problem, `ng is not defined` but I will create a new question for that.

Comment: most likely you are using syntax from alpha, there's many changes on beta, once again check the 5 min quickstart and you'll catch most of them